# Add multi line description

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the Youtube Data Api to upload a video. I'm trying to get the description to look like this:

```
Hello

Multi line description
```

I've tried to accomplish this by doing:

```
"description": ('''Hello
                Multi line description'''),
 
 returns -> 'description:': 'Hello\nMulti line description',
```

However when I upload this every other field other than the description is included. How could I add multi lines to the description? Thank you.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63922126/12511801) and check the response of the request. You'll see that the video description has `\n` twice.

Comment: That solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63922126/12511801) and check the response of the request.

You'll see that the video description uses the new line **`\n`** twice.