# Extract and download chapters from youtube videos

Tags: python, youtube

Let's say I want to download a youtube video that contains chapters like this:

[image]

and I want to download this video with each chapter as an individual video. i.e, a video with 5 chapters should be downloaded as 5 separate videos. We can do the following:

```
from moviepy.video.io.ffmpeg_tools import ffmpeg_extract_subclip
required_video_file = "filename.mp4"
with open("times.txt") as f:
  times = f.readlines()
times = [x.strip() for x in times] 
for time in times:
  starttime = int(time.split("-")[0])
  endtime = int(time.split("-")[1])
  ffmpeg_extract_subclip(required_video_file, starttime, endtime, targetname=str(times.index(time)+1)+".mp4")
```

where `times.txt` contains the timestamps of each chapter. This way is very tedious. How can I improve this?

Comment: what do you expect? Do you want to get times from YouTube? Maybe you should check YouTube API?

Comment: [How do I get info about a Youtube video's chapters from the API? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63821605/how-do-i-get-info-about-a-youtube-videos-chapters-from-the-api)